# What exactly does `ssh -T user@domain verify` do?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, ssh, terminal

The example I'm specifically thinking of is:

```
ssh -T git@github.com verify
```

Looking at the docs (`man ssh`) I can see that `-T` is the flag to "Disable pseudo-terminal allocation", but what implications does that actually have on the verification?

Does this command go to the network at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Disable pseudo-terminal allocation

This means that the command `verify` is run directly on the other side and the standard input/output/error are connected directly to your local terminal.

For commands, there is usually no difference, but it is difference if you want to run interactive scripts (shell). In that point, your output would not be handled by remote terminal, but with your own and the output would not be so pretty. You can try with `ssh -T other_host`, where you have terminal access (you don't have on github). On github, it is also one of the resources-saving task, since TTY allocation is "not for free" if you have [31 million users (October 2018)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub).

Comment: Number of GitHub users are now 31 million (October 2018)

Answer (score 2):

> ssh -T git@github.com verify

This logs into the account `git@github.com` and executes the command `verify` there. So it definitely goes to the network. The command `verify` is specific to github and creates a token which you can use to prove to the support that you are the owner of a specific key used to log into this account.